Solana web3.js getParsedTransaction returning null
I am writing a script that listens to Solana logs on a certain account and want to send transaction details whenever certain Program conditions are met, as seen below.
connection.onLogs(
            publicKey,
            async (logs, context) => {
                    const timeAt = new Date().toString();

                    if (logs && logs.logs.some(log => log.includes(INSTRUCTION_NAME))) {
                         let transactionDetails = await connection.getParsedTransaction(logs.signature, {maxSupportedTransactionVersion:0});
                         console.log(transactionDetails);   
                    }
                },
            "confirmed",
        );

My issue is that most of the time this transactionDetails object is being returned as null, I am trying to look into it and why they are null but I haven't found any reason as to why this is happening.

If you're using a public / load-balanced RPC endpoint, you might be running into an issue where the transaction was confirmed by the RPC node your websocket is connected to, but then getParsedTransaction hits a node that's behind. You might need to add some retry logic when fetching the transaction.
